# How to prove this inequality: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\text{lcm}(i,j)\ge\frac{7}{8}n^3$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, summation, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $n$ be postive integers.  Show that
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}[i,j]\ge\dfrac{7}{8}n^3\,,$$ where $[a,b]$ denote the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$.

For $n=1,2,3 $, it is clear.  How to prove this inequality? Thanks!

Comment: I assume induction?

Comment: If you use the trivial inequality $[i,j]\geq \max(i,j)$, I think you get $2n^3/3$ as a lower bound, which is already quite close.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\,\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\,\text{lcm}(i,j)$.  We have $S_1=1\geq \dfrac{7}{8}\cdot 1^3$ and $S_2=7\geq \dfrac{7}{8}\cdot 2^3$.  Assume that $n>2$ is an integer such that $$S_{n-1}\geq \dfrac{7}{8}\,(n-1)^3\,.$$
Then,
$$S_{n}-S_{n-1}=n+2\,\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\,\text{lcm}(k,n)\,.$$
Since $n>3$,
$$S_n-S_{n-1}\geq n+2\,\big(\text{lcm}(n-1,n)+\text{lcm}(n-2,n)\big)\,.$$
We see that $\text{lcm}(n-1,n)=(n-1)n$ and $\text{lcm}(n-2,n)\geq \dfrac{(n-2)n}{2}$.  Ergo,
$$S_n-S_{n-1}\geq n+2\,\left((n-1)n+\frac{(n-2)n}{2}\right)=3n^2-3n\,.$$
For $n>2$, we have
$$3n^2-3n\geq 3\cdot 3^2-3\cdot 3=18>7;$$
therefore,
$$3n^2-3n> \frac{7}{8}\,(3n^2-3n+1)=\frac{7}{8}\,\big(n^3-(n-1)^3\big)\,.$$
Consequently,
$$S_n>\frac{7}{8}\,\big(n^3-(n-1)^3\big)+S_{n-1}\geq \frac{7}{8}\,\big(n^3-(n-1)^3\big)+\frac{7}{8}\,(n-1)^3=\frac{7}{8}\,n^3\,.$$
By induction, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\,\sum_{j=1}^n\,\text{lcm}(i,j)=S_n\geq \frac{7}{8}\,n^3$$
for every positive integer $n$.  The equality holds if and only if $n=2$.

Let $H_n:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\,\dfrac1k$ for each positive integer $n$. 
 Apparently, we also have $$S_n\geq 2\,\sum_{k=1}^n\,k^2\,H_k-\frac{n(n+1)(4n-1)}{6}\,.$$
The inequality above becomes an equality if and only if $n=1$ and $n=2$.

If $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant, then using $H_n>\ln(n)+\gamma$ for every positive integer $n$ yields
$$\begin{align}S_n&\geq 2\,\int_0^n\,x^2\,\big(\ln(x)+\gamma)\,\text{d}x-\frac{n(n+1)(4n-1)}{6}
\\&=\dfrac{2n^3}{9}\,\big(3\ln(n)-1\big)+\frac{2\gamma n^3}{3}-\frac{n(n+1)(4n-1)}{6}\,.\end{align}$$
I am going to predict again as I have done in many threads that
$$S_n=\alpha n^3\ln(n)+\beta n^3+o(n^3)\,,$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants.  (Clearly, $\alpha\geq \frac{2}{3}$.)  However, I can be wrong about this.  I have not tried to find an upper bound of $S_n$ that is of the form $\mathcal{O}\big(n^3\,\ln(n)\big)$.  (The OP posted [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618203/how-prove-this-inequality-sum-i-1n-sum-j-1n-textlcmi-j-le-fracn) regarding an upper bound.)

Comment: I don't understand the line $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} lcm(k, n) \geq lcm(n-1,n)+lcm(n-2,n)$? (I think I am being stupid help)

Comment: I just took two terms out of $n-1$ terms:  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\,\text{lcm}(k,n)\geq \sum_{k=n-2}^{n-1}\,\text{lcm}(k,n)\,.$$

Comment: Ooooh It's $\geq$... Sorry I am being stupid and missing obvious stuff haha.